# I need help on combining functions using numbers

Tags: python, function, numbers

I'm new to programming and right now I'm learning about functions and everything related to them. I've been making some example of my own, and I ran into a problem.

```
 def test(x):
    number = x + 1
    return (number)
def test2(y):
    number2 = test(y) + 2
    print (number2)
test2(1)
```

If I print this function, it would work. However I don't understand something. Why is it that when I put number 1 into test2(y), it also goes into test(x)? Why does this happen?

Comment: Using one as an example test(x) returns 2 and test2(y) returns 4.

Comment: Nevermind, misread the first return as print ;-)

Comment: Now for a real hint: What happens when you compute `number2`?

Answer (score 0):

You defined `def test2(y):` so when you run `test2(1)` then it creates local variable `y` inside `test2` and it assigns `y = 1` - and then it starts to execute commands inside `test2`.

Inside `test2` you execute `test(y)` so it gets value from `y` and executes `test(1)`. And again: you defined `def test(x)` so it creates local variable `x` inside `test`, and it assigns `x = 1` and then it starts to executes commands inside `test`. So now `1` is inside `test`